# Stream CDC change with Kafka and Spark still processes it in batches, whereas we wish to process each record

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm still new in Spark and I want to learn more about it. I want to build and data pipeline architecture with Kafka and Spark.Here is my proposed architecture where PostgreSQL provide data for Kafka. The condition is the PostgreSQL are not empty and I want to catch any CDC change in the database. At the end,I want to grab the Kafka Message and process it in stream with Spark so i can get analysis about what happen at the same time when the CDC event happen.

However, when I try to run an simple stream, it seems Spark receive the data in stream, but process the data in batch, which not my goal. I have see some article that the source of data for this case came from API which we want to monitor, and there's limited case for Database to Database streaming processing. I have done the process before with Kafka to another database, but i need to transform and aggregate the data (I'm not use Confluent and rely on generic Kafka+Debezium+JDBC connectors)

According to my case, is Spark and Kafka can meet the requirement? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed such pipelines and if you use Structured Streaming KAFKA in continuous or non-continuous mode, you will always get a microbatch. ***You can process the individual records, so not sure what the issue is.***

If you want to process per record, then use the Spring Boot KAFKA setup for consumption of KAFKA messages, that can work in various ways, and fulfill your need. Spring Boor offers various modes of consumption.

Of course Spark Structured Streaming can be done using Scala and has a lot of support obviating extra work elsewhere.

https://medium.com/@contactsunny/simple-apache-kafka-producer-and-consumer-using-spring-boot-41be672f4e2b  This article discusses the single message processing approach.

Comment: I want to produce individual record in Spark. I will check Spring Boot capability to transform it

Comment: But i only want to put my Spring Boot as consumer, so I let Debezium run on my Server and get anything from Postgres. Is it okay?

Comment: That's what I meant indeed. Will add that.

Comment: So i have clarified the task. Receive the message from kafka, break it into several new structures to another database and store the new structures into target database (there's also update and delete operations in the target database)

Comment: And maybe i will try my chance with Python as the implementation are pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry @thebluephantom, i forgot it. Thanks to the answer